# Font-family for svg text is not working?

Tags: javascript, html, svg

1) What is the defalut font family for text in SVG?

2) I am trying to render on svg text with dynamic font .For first time when I am applying the font Its not working , for the 2nd time onwards It works fine. 
Can any one help me on this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your First Ans Is Here :  https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/fonts.html#FontDescriptions

Comment: 1) depends on your browser and maybe operating system. 2) show the code.

Comment: hey thanks for your effort. I got my answer. The font should be loaded in browser before your code is executed.

Comment: @RobertLongson The project code structure is very lengthy. So it bit difficult for me to produce the code here. anyways thanks to all.

Comment: @biswajit-rout you'll be needing to create a [mcve] then.

Comment: Ok thanks for your advice. I will do that from next.

Answer (score 0):

**There's no default font (`font-face/font-family`) mentioned. in `W3C`.**

NOTE:

> If you specify a font on a web page or in an SVG file that the user
>   doesn't have available, then you're relying on the browser or browser
>   plugin to find a reasonably good match for that font. Given only the
>   font name, it's going to do a bad job of matching. Use the font
>   attribute with a combination of the font-family and other attributes
>   to provide some information that will get a font more like the one you
>   want. The generic family names you can use are 'serif', 'sans-serif',
>   'cursive', 'fantasy', and 'monospace' (from the CSS specification).
>   You can also use other family names like "Times", "Baskerville",
>   "Verdena", and "Symbol."

Comment: What will I do if want to use some other custom fonts except the browser fonts.

Comment: Well there is a default font, it is just left up to the browser to decide what that should be. https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/single-page.html#text-FontFamilyProperty